# My prefix was talking, my suffix is just like me and you

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

Again another Riley riddle. They popular and easy, so I'm going start to make harder ones later.

> My prefix was talking, what does it mean,
>
> My suffix is just like me and you,
>
> My infix knows what you're thinking of,
>
> And altogether I will talk for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are a:

> SPOKESPERSON

My prefix was talking:

> SPOKE

My infix knows what you're thinking:

> ESP

My suffix is just like me and you:

> PERSON